# How to clear datagridview typed cell value in c# .net windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview in my application i am validating our datagridview for numneric value,
I am using this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) 
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = dataGridView1[6, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            char[] chars = e.FormattedValue.ToString().ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i have a problem with this, when we typed in cell so it did not clear cell after the message show,
I have to press, Backspace key for clear the cell.

I want to automatically cleared after wrong entry or `MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");` this message show.

How it can be possible?

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried setting cell.Text = "" ?

Comment: There is no property of DataGridViewTextBoxCell as "Text". Tried cell.Value = "" but not working...

Comment: I think i found the solution

MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");
cell.Value = "";
dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();

This clears the DataGridViewTextBoxCell...:)